# Ignore value read using input stream

Tags: c++, io, stream

Is there a way to "dump" a value read using a stream without reading it into a dummy variable?

For example, if I have a file which contains two strings and an integer, e.g., "foo.txt" looks like this:

```
foo      bar      6
foofoo   barbar   8
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
std::string str;
int i;
std::ifstream file("foo.txt");
file >> str >> nullptr >> i;
```

and have `str = "foo"` and `i = 6` afterwards?

Comment: Should be possible to define an empty class, with an overloaded formatted extraction operator that works on an rvalue reference to a temporary instance of the class. So, the short answer to your question seems to be: "yes, there's a way to do that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) but it is pretty much useless because:

1. It can only skip one particular delimiter character, not a character class (e.g. any whitespace).
2. It needs to be invoked multiple times to skip a word.

---

You can write a function `ignore_word(std::istream& s)`:

```
std::istream& ignore_word(std::istream& s) {
    while(s && std::isspace(s.peek()))
        s.get();
    while(s && !std::isspace(s.peek()))
        s.get();
    return s;
}

int main() {
    std::istringstream s("foo bar 6");
    std::string foo;
    int i;
    s >> foo;
    ignore_word(s);
    s >> i;
    std::cout << foo << ' ' << i << '\n';
}
```